# A segmentation fault with malloc while populating a structure fields in a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct defined as

```
struct _element;
typedef struct _element Element;

struct _element {

    char* StudentName;
    char* StudentID;
    int StudentMarks;
};
```

A pointer to an `Element` struct is declared globally as

```
Element * ePtr;
```

Now I have a function that returns a pointer to an `Element` struct. This is defined as shown below. The same `ePtr` which was declared globally is populated in this function and then returned.

```
Element * CreateElement(char * jName, char * jID, int jMarks)
{
    printf("CreateElement \n");
    puts(jName); puts(jID); printf("%d\n",jMarks);

    ePtr->StudentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(jName));

    strcpy(ePtr->StudentName, jName);

    printf("After Creation \n");
    puts(ePtr->StudentName);

    return ePtr;
}
```

I am calling this function using

```
ePtr = CreateElement(iName,iID,iMarks);
```

from another function. The values stored in the parameters are correct, as shown by `puts` and `printf` commands just below the function call line.

My problem is that I'm getting a segmentation fault at the

```
ePtr->StudentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(jName));
```

line. I checked the same using gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you allocating any memory for `ePtr`?

Just declaring a pointer to this struct globally isn't enough: you'll need to `malloc` some memory for it also: `ePtr = malloc(sizeof(Element);`.

Also be sure to add an extra slot in the `malloc` for your strings for the null terminator.

Generally, always initialize your pointers to `NULL` - you **can** do that when you declare the global: `Element *ePtr = NULL;`. Furthermore, try to get your `ePtr` out of the global-scope, and, check for `NULL` before you use a pointer, as with `ePtr` in your `CreateElement` method.

Comment: But I'm not sure how much memory to allocate to ePtr. Because the fields can be of varying length. In fact I tried doing what you wrote. GCC gave an error that it isn't of const size.

Comment: That's fine, you'll `malloc` space for those pointers when the time comes, as you are already doing. doing a `malloc(sizeof(Element))` gives you enough space for the `int` and the pointers, you're already making space for the _pointed-to_ strings in your code

Comment: I replaced the global declaration with 
Element * ePtr = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element)); 

Now it says :
error: initializer element is not constant

Comment: it's because it's file-scope, try it within a function, e.g. `main`, or at the beginning of your `CreateElement` function,  or an init function.

Comment: in the original problem, gdb shows the seg fault happening right after `ePtr->StudentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(jName));` is executed.

Comment: I tried `* ePtr = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));` in the driver function. The seg fault happens here now. It doesn't go into the function being called.

Comment: don't dereference on the assignment: you're assigning _to_ the pointer: `ePtr = malloc(sizeof(Element);`

Comment: Yeah, I got that bit. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign any memory to

```
ePtr = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
```

before you start assigning values to it and ultimately return it from the function.

Also you need to allow space for the nul terminator of your string

```
ePtr->StudentName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(jName) + 1));
```

Finally don't forget to allocate memory for and copy the value of the ID, and copy the studentMarks into Element.

Remember, the Element is fixed-size.  It needs memory to hold the two `char *` as well as the one `int`.  It does not matter that the strings are variable length when allocating memory for Element.

Comment: I tried the (strlen(jName) +1) thing. Giving the same error. And no, I cannot allocate memory to ePtr beforehand, because the fields can be of varying length.

Comment: Wrong... Element's size is fixed.  It is the size of two char * plus the size of one int (plus in the general case potentially size for padding, which is not likely to be the case here).  The thing that the char * point to, on the other hand, is variable length.

Comment: But when I do that, it does show the error that `error: initializer element is not constant `

Comment: Yeah, it worked when I put the `malloc` in the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign some memory for ePtr before you can assign memory to the char* that it contains. Do a malloc on your ePtr at the start of the function.

There is also little point in declaring ePtr globally, but this isn't what is breaking the program.

```
ePtr = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));
```

You should probably also check if ePtr is null after this before using it (can be null if out of memory as well as some other issues).

Comment: To copy paste my response from another answer on this thread:

 
I replaced the global declaration with `Element * ePtr = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));` Now it says : `error: initializer element is not constant`

Comment: I haven't coded in a c in a while but if I remember correctly I don't think you're allowed to call a malloc globally like that, you'll need to do Element* ePtr; global and then malloc it in your function.